# Server works, domain does not with VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, apache2

I have to deal with clear VPS with Ubuntu 16.04; Apache (and domain).

The server itself works fine via ip-address. I have successfully installed php via ssh, so now I even have some Linux experience.

But the domain doesn't work. Trying to access it just with browser I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. The same through Hotspot shield vpn, but with Zen mate I get `dial tcp: lookup mistod.com on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving`, although it is not server's ip.

In host provider site I set it's nameservers for domain. Via ssh in Apache I created and enabled config for that domain, specifying it in `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` attributes.

Googling, I found solution, where man wrotes that the ssl should be installed, so I went to Let's encrypt, followed, instruction for certbot, but stuck in command `sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core`: it gives error `system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using...` .

I also tried to install certbot via `apt-get`, and it installed, then I installed Apache plugin, but the final command `sudo certbot --apache` returns `An unexpected error occurred`.

Is it something in hosting-provider-side, so I need to contact them, or it's me doing wrong something?

Comment: Okey, for that who minused, can You at least explain what's wrong with questions itself?

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Comment: You failed to identify the root of your problem. If `mistod.com` is indeed your domain name then the root of your problem is that your domain is not properly set up yet at  the designated name servers: NS1.STABLEHOST.COM and  NS2.STABLEHOST.COM - all other operations that require your DNS to work, your website,  LetsEncrypt, email etc. etc. will fail until you resolve that.

Comment: @Rob, well after a whole day of research it seems, that the problem is in "A" record in dns. Current provider does not give access to change dns records, but for test, I went to my provider, and for my own domain name I changed A record ip to current server ip and all works with my domain. So, as I understood, I need somehow to deal with A record but with current provider nameservers or on vps create own nameservers and A record for them. I installed webmin, probably it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to make things work, if your provider doesn't gives opportunities to edit dns record except nameservers, you can for example, free Cloudflare dns.

You will need create free account add there your domain, then, where you ordering your domain you should change current nameservers to Cloudlflare's nameservers, that you can get from Cloundflare's dashboard.

The last one in Cloudflare's dashboard add "A" dns record passing vps' ip-address.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/how-to/create-dns-records/

That's work for me. Notice, that after changing nameservers it needs some time to propagate changes through web (up to 24 hours).